# Symfony2 update entity field with dynamic form

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm trying to update my entities using some dynamically generated forms in order to perform the modification. The values are sent with ajax using [x-editable](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/index.html). My problem is that I cannot perform the modification, as the form wont be submitted, and I dont know why.

Here is my current piece of code :

```
// I can pass all those data using X-editable without a problem
$id         = 1;              // entity ID
$value      = 'someNewValue'; // new value
$type       = 'text';         // type of field
$schem      = array('AppBundle', 'membre', 'prenom'); // The stuff used to to work this out
$em         = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$entity     = $em->getRepository($schem[0] . ':' . ucfirst($schem[1]) )->find($id); // Now I've got my entity

// I create a dynamic form with no CSRF protection (as I read in some other post)
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($entity, array(

        'csrf_protection' => false
    )
)->add($schem[2])
  ->getForm();

var_dump($form->isValid()); // false
$form->get($schem[2])->submit($value); // trying to submit the new value
var_dump($form->isValid()); // still false

var_dump($form->getErrorsAsString()); // Shows ''
```

Here is the targeted field of my entity (in this example)

```
/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(name="prenom", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $prenom;
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: $schem contains three informations, first the bundle name string (here AppBundle), second the entity in lowercase (here membre) and third the field to update on the entity (here prenom), which is targeted by $schem[2].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a solution.
The main problem took place on the line where I tried to submit the new value

```
$form->get($schem[2])->submit($value);
```

I dont know why but this doesnt work at all. In fact I had to use `submit` on the form itself, like this :

```
$form->submit( array($field => $value) );
```

where `$field` is the updated field in my entity and `$value` is the new value. For more informations check [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/direct_submit.html#calling-form-submit-manually)